# Disable checkbox if the other isn't checked jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to have at least one checkbox always checked.  Both can be checked at the same time, but I need at least one to be always checked.

I attempted to do this w/ the code below.  The idea is to check if the checkbox isn't checked, and add a disabled property to the other checkbox.

So for example...

If letters isn't checked, check numbers and disable it so user cannot uncheck it.

```
if (letters.checked === false) { // if letters isn't checked
    numbers.prop("disabled", true); // disable numbers
    numbers.checked = true; // keep numbers checked
} else if (numbers.checked === false) { // else if numbers isn't checked
    letters.prop("disabled", true); // disable letters
    letters.checked = true; // keep letters checked
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5axt8/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Like this you mean `:)` working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3dC3/

- I have added `.on` change event.
- Also you can use `.is` checked for checking if it is checked or not.

Hope this fits your needs.

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
        var letters = $("#letters"),
            numbers = $("#numbers");

        if (!letters.is(':checked')) { // if letters isn't checked
            numbers.prop("disabled", true); // disable numbers
            numbers.checked = true; // keep numbers checked
        } else if (!numbers.is(':checked')) { // else if numbers isn't checked
            letters.prop("disabled", true); // disable letters
            letters.checked = true; // keep letters checked
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man!  I added [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3dC3/1/) to it so that if both are checked, disabled attribute is turned off. ;)

Comment: @Matthew all good bruvoo! #lookatthatsmoothbeauty fiddle! Glad it helped `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to put that logic into an event handler if you want it to fire every time the checked states change. Currently, it only runs on `$(document).ready` and never runs after that.

Comment: An example of how the Original Poster could do that might be good :)

Comment: Catch a man a fish, teach a man to fish, etc. I hate when people spoon feed other people code on SO. If you can't take a little help and run to google with it, you're never gonna make it as a software developer, in my opinion.